# Excel Add-In Not Loading When Exporting Data From Database

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I've created an Excel Add-In that is used by many people at my work all the time.  It works fine when I open an Excel file from my computer or our shared network, but when I Export data from one of our Query Report Writer Systems (Data Access Studio - ReportsNow), the Add-In is missing from the Ribbon.  Once this happens, every Excel application opened thereafter, whether from my local computer or the shared network, the Add-In is not there!  As a workaround, I go to Options > Add-ins > Excel Add-Ins > Go and uncheck and re-check... then it appears.  I've searched for quite a while and cannot find the answer.

**So far, I have tried the following:**

• Excel Options > Add-ins > Excel Add-Ins > Go ... It's Checked
• Excel Options > Add-ins > Disabled Items > Go ... It's not on the disabled list
• Right click the XLAM file > Properties > General Tab > Select Unblock...(This actually wasn't even an option for me. The UNBLOCK check box did not appear on the window).
• Excel Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations... I added my location: C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns
• Excel Options > Trust Center> Addins ... I made sure that "Require Application Addins to be signed by Trusted Publisher" was unticked

### What Am I Missing?!?!

**Additional info**

• The Add-In is built entirely in VBA and uses IRibbonControls to create buttons on the Ribbon (GetVisible, GetLabel, GetImage, GetSize, GetScreentip, etc)
• We also have the EssBase SmartView Add-in, which is always available... but Oracle created that one :).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect the application in question (Query Report Writer System) opens Excel using Automation. This means that Excel add-ins are not loaded and also everything from XLSTART is ignored. There isn't much you can do about this other than contacting the builders of the report writer system and let them know you don't like what you see.

Comment: Possibly... I just added another bullet point to the bottom of my question. Our SmartView Add-in is still available, which makes me think there should be a way to keep my Add-in available too.

Comment: That is probably a (.NET) COM add-in, those do load funny enough.